# Не отображается абзац

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При копировании текста на странице Rails-приложения он отображается с пробелами вместо абзацев, а если вводить текст с клавиатуры, то Enter срабатывает как сохранение текста. Как сделать чтобы в приложении отображались абзацы?

Форма:

```
<%= form_with(model: act, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if act.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(act.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited 
this act from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% act.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description, id: :act_description, class: 
"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

вьюха:

```
<h1>Acts:</h1>
<%= link_to 'New Act', new_act_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
%>
<br><br>

<% @acts.each do |act| %>
  <% if act.user == current_user %>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <article class="lead"> <%= act.description %>
        <span class="float-right">
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_act_path(act), class: "btn btn-
primary btn-sm" %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', act, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 
'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm" %>
        </span>
        </article>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Act', new_act_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
```

Comment: Кажется, нам немного не хватает кода вашей страницы приложения. Ну хотя бы той формы, куда вы вводите текст. А вообще похоже вам нужен WYSIWYG редактор какой-то

Comment: Я пробовал WYSIWYG редактор, но это ничем не помогло. Или я что-то не так сделал... в форме я заменил form.text_field на form.text_area и ентер в форме уже переключает на следующую строчку, но после сохранения  во вьюхе опять таки весь текст слипается в одну длинную строчку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь поняла. Вам нужно конвертить разрывы строк во что-то, что понимает HTML. В рельсах для этого есть [simple_format](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format). То есть, во вьюхе должно быть:

```
<article class="lead"> <%= simple_format(act.description) %>
```

Comment: Действительно проблема была в этом. Спасибо за подсказку. Теперь все работает как нужно)))

Comment: @ВолодимирЛопатовський, всегда рада помочь :) В следующий раз сразу добавляйте код к вопросу, так гораздо проще отвечать